# kohana next iterator

Tags: php, orm, iterator, kohana

I am using the next() iterator in order to get the second element from a colection, but this next() returns me an oject like: Resource id #115 .
the code:

```
   $first_two = $product->images->limit(2)->find_all();
   $second = next($first_two);
```

and next($first_two); gives: Resource id #115 for example.

How can i make it show just 115 (only the id?)

i need it for making a query after this id.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$second->id`? If you're using ORM, which I think you are, then `find_all()` returns Database_result trough which you can iterate.

Comment: What does `echo Debug::dump($first_two)` outputs?